# Vue 3 server side rendering is changing single and double quotes in style tag to HTML Entity Codes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, server-side-rendering

I am trying to use Vue 3 to render a template and data to a string using vue/server-renderer. I am using the below code to generate the html string:
`const app = createApp({
data: () => testData,
template: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './../templates/sample.html'), 'utf-8'),
});

```
htmlString = await require('vue/server-renderer').renderToString(app,context);`
```

For whatever reason, the string that is being returned is changing the single quotes and double quotes to the html entity code in the style tag only (ex a single quote become &39;). This is making the styling of the template break. You can see an example of what happens below.

[Results of renderToString](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlY5W.png)

I have tried using open-quote and close-quote which does fix the problem but then the quotes show. I could use no-open-quote and no-close-quote, but I want to be able to actually write words for content as well.

Has anyone ran into this problem before and if so how did you fix it?

For reference I am using the latest version of Vue (3.2.47)

Comment: The template of the Vue component should not be a full document (that contains `html`, `head`, `body`, and `style` tags). Please refer to [this example](https://github.com/vitejs/vite-plugin-vue/tree/main/playground/ssr-vue) to see how to create an SSR project

Comment: Ah that is very good to know. After only rendering the body and wrapping it in the other tags afterwards, it works now. Thank you!